# date function myql query for expiry date option

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I have a table named coupons. I want to display coupons which have expiry date coming soon. I am stuck with the query. Any suggestion please.

```
SELECT * FROM coupons  WHERE  c_date_expired BETWEEN 
CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

[image]

I want to return the last c_id i.e 3 because it is going to expire soon.

Comment: what's "not" working?

Comment: ^ that was a question asking for clarification. Questions deserves answers, just like you asked one ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is not returning me the required row.

Comment: and what is the requered row? could you show a little example to clarify=?

Comment: you may have to edit your post to show us what the db schema and values are @tabia

Comment: @DamianLattenero i have edited post

Comment: @tabia ok, I edited the answer, now I can understad, great job editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add Date in front of your Date_add:

```
SELECT * FROM coupons  
WHERE  c_date_expired >= CURDATE() 
AND c_date_expired <= (CURDATE() + interval 5 day)
```

Comment: mmm @tabia, what about now? I'm trying to guess what you want, but I feel I'm close, you tell me :)

Comment: I have always loved to help @tabia! don't forget voting if you liked :D